# Celery MongoDB backend removes old results

Tags: python, mongodb, celery

In my Flask project I'm using MongoDB as a broker for Celery tasks and also as a storage for task results:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'mongodb://10.10.10.110:27017/production'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'mongodb://10.10.10.10:27017/'

CELERY_MONGODB_BACKEND_SETTINGS = {
    'database': 'production', 
   'taskmeta_collection': 'celery_tasks',
}
```

But when I query the results from `celery_tasks` collection I notice that it automatically removes old results and only shows me the ones for the last two days.

Is there any additional configuration that defines TTL for task results and how can I prevent celery from deleting old results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `result_expires=0`

> A value of None or 0 means results will never expire (depending on backend specifications).

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#result-expires